# Changing a table's contents with just mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge table of 100k plus entries. In it a `TEXT` column named `body` exist. The column can have upto 1000 UTF-8 characters. All the fields are filled up. I want to replace all occurrence of a string "ABC" with "XYZ" in each individual rows of the column. I know how to do this using traditional fetch-change-update method using a backend language. How can i do the same thing with just mysql. Just by running a query. If i can, how? What should be the query type i have to use.

Comment: Does the `REPLACE()` function not work? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Thanks :), I didnt even know about this function. Result of learning mysql based upon my needs rather than a systematic study.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  yourTable
SET
  yourField = REPLACE(yourField, 'abc', 'xyz')
```